# Async EF 6.0 taking longer than sync

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, entity-framework-6

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();
            Task t = MainAsync();
            t.Wait();

            stopWatch.Stop();
            var sec = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


        }


        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            FutureEntityTestEntities db = new FutureEntityTestEntities();

            var q1 = await db.Table1.ToListAsync();


            var q2 = await db.Table1.ToListAsync();



        }
```

this query takes 2700 miliseconds on average.

however when i just do normal tolist without async it takes 1800 ms;

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FutureEntityTestEntities db = new FutureEntityTestEntities();

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();

            var q1 = db.Table1.ToList();

             var q2 = db.Table1.ToList();

            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

the problem is i dont understand, it should take what the synchronous time divided by 2 = 900ms but it adds another 900 ms which is fairly strange.

Edit: Thx for the answer now.I modified the code as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch2;
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();
            Task t = MainAsync();


            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            FutureEntityTestEntities db = new FutureEntityTestEntities();

            Task<List<Table1>> q1 = db.Table1.ToListAsync();

            Task<List<Table1>> q2 = db.Table1.ToListAsync();

            await Task.WhenAll(q1, q2);

        }
```

now however it takes on average 500 ms.

I am going to research on the internet as to why and post the answer here, if somebody has an answer please respond thx.

Comment: Probably your time measurements are flawed. The numbers just don't add up. There's lots of one-time init in EF. Run the test 10 times.

Answer (score 4):

You're not concurrently executing the two `.ToListAsync()`'s if that's what you're expecting. If you wanted them to execute concurrently you would need to do:

```
// Kick off both queries concurrency
Task<List<Table1>> q1 = db.Table1.ToListAsync();
Task<List<Table1>> q2 = db.Table1.ToListAsync();

// Wait for both to finish before returning
await Task.WhenAll(q1, q2);
```

Answer (score 4):

> the problem is i dont understand, it should take what the synchronous time divided by 2

That's incorrect. These two queries aren't running concurrently, they're running sequentiality one after the other. `await` means: *asynchronously wait for the operation to complete.*

If you want to execute them concurrently, you can spin of both operations and then use `await Task.WhenAll` and pass in both tasks.

As a side note, using `async-await` doesn't come for free. There's the compiler which does work for us of generating a state-machine behind the scenes. Although very optimized, still has some overhead.